# Didn't understand how it works

Tags: jquery, css

As we use Css and jQuery to toggle menu in mobile view and after toggle, if we expand, whole menu div is hidden in desktop view. so as for solution we use:

```
$(function(){
  $(".nav-btn").click(function(){
    $(".nav").toggle(400, function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("expand").css('display','');
    });
  });
});
```

I didn't understand how how that callback function makes menu again visible in desktop view.

Comment: *"how that callback function makes menu again visible"* - The call to `.css('display','')` removes any `display` CSS rule.  When the element was "toggled" it was hidden by way of a CSS `display` rule.  By removing that rule, the element is visible again.

Comment: How is this a bad question?

Comment: Well the title says nothing about it, for a start.

Comment: this is my first time asking a question here.... from next time i'll make sure to be clear in title @Utkanos

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter in `toggle` defines the string or number determining how long the animation will run. So, when you are giving `400` it stays only for that much time in milliseconds. The default value is always `400`.

Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively.

Here is the simple example below. What it does is that when you click on the `nav-btn` then it will apply the css as defined in the callback waiting for `400` milliseconds.

```js
$(".nav-btn").click(function(){
  $(".nav").toggle(400, function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("expand").css('display','');
  });
});
```

```css
.expand{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='nav-btn'>
 <div class='nav'>someContent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't record it saying less than 15 reputaion something...